# Explicit cast required to pointer to void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have the following function signature

```
int foo(void **)
```

and am trying to give it a pointer to a `char` pointer, i.e. `char **`. My compiler is complaining with the following warning

```
argument of type "char **" is incompatible with parameter of type "void **"
```

Is this to be expected? I know passing a `char *` to a function expecting a `void *` requires no explicit cast but is this true for pointers to pointers?

Note : this is explicitly a `C` question. I would be interested if different `C` versions treat this differently.

Comment: I believe it's because the standard only requires *conversions* to/from `void *` be implicit, but such conversion may be non-trivial. As such, a conversion from `char **` to `void **` and dereferencing such a pointer *may* lead to undefined behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [Chapter 22: Pointers to Pointers](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html):

> One side point about pointers to pointers and memory allocation: although the `void *` type, as returned by `malloc`, is a "generic pointer," suitable for assigning to or from pointers of any type, the hypothetical type **`void **` is not a "generic pointer to pointer"**.

So, only `void *` is a generic pointer. `void **` is not generic pointer. Therefore the argument passed to your function must be of type `void **`.

Also see [**C-FAQ**](http://www.c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html):

> **There is no generic pointer-to-pointer type in C**. `void *` acts as a generic pointer only because conversions (if necessary) are applied automatically when other pointer types are assigned to and from `void *`'s; these conversions cannot be performed if an attempt is made to indirect upon a `void **` value which points at a pointer type other than `void *`. When you make use of a `void **` pointer value (for instance, when you use the `*` operator to access the `void *` value to which the `void **` points), the compiler has no way of knowing whether that `void *` value was once converted from some other pointer type. It must assume that it is nothing more than a `void *`; it cannot perform any implicit conversions.
>
> In other words, any `void **` value you play with must be the address of an actual `void *` value somewhere; casts like `(void **)&dp`, though they may shut the compiler up, are nonportable (and may not even do what you want; see also question 13.9). If the pointer that the `void **` points to is not a `void *`, and if it has a different size or representation than a `void *`, then the compiler isn't going to be able to access it correctly.