# what is the difference while typecasting a pointer as &(int*) and (int*)& while assigning it to some pointer variable?

Tags: c

If we have a `void` pointer and we try to assign it the address of some pointer variable (for instance, a pointer to int ), then what is the difference between the statements 1 and 2.

For statement 2 , I am getting `lvalue error`, but I am not getting the reason behind this - `ptr` is `lvalue` only so why does it show an error?

```
int a;
int *ptr =&a ;
1. void *p =(int*)&ptr;
2. void *p=&(int*)ptr;
```

Comment: Both are wrong - just use [`void *p = ptr;`](https://ideone.com/OwY9YH).

Comment: `&(int *)ptr` is equivalent to `&((int *)ptr)` so has the effect of computing `(int *)ptr` as a temporary (which is not an lvalue) first and the `&` then attempts to obtain the address of that temporary.     `(int *)&ptr`  computes the address of `ptr` (i.e. `&ptr`) first - which is valid since `ptr` is an lvalue - and then converts the value to be of type `int *`.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a good question. And @Peter please use the answers section for answers.

Comment: @Peter no - it is an equivalent to `error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand` consequently does not have any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to section 6.5.4 of the C99 specification, line 4, footnote 89, available online [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> A cast does not yield an lvalue

When we look at your code:

```
int a;
int *ptr =&a ;
1. void *p =(int*)&ptr;
2. void *p=&(int*)ptr;
```

In case of 1: A `void` pointer is assigned what has been typecast to `int*`. This is valid. In fact the following statements also are valid:

```
3. void *p = (int*)123;
4. void *p = (int*)a;
5. void *p = (int*)ptr;
```

But in case of 2: `(int*)ptr` has become an rvalue and then you are using `&` on that rvalue. It fails stating: `lvalue required as unary '&' operand`

For 2., it is not the assignment to `void*` that is causing the problem but the operator `&` on an rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the second one `void *p=&(int*)ptr;` has incorrect syntax as `&` requires an lvalue.

```
int *n;
void *p = &n;
void *q = &(void *)n;  //incorrect syntax will not compile at all
void *w = &(int *)n;   //incorrect syntax will not compile at all
```

So the difference is: `&(some_type *)n` will not compile at all, and does not have any sense.
[Sample code](https://ideone.com/bZUYFe).

`&(int*)ptr` is just not valid in C.

Why? Because p and (type *)p are completely different. p is object which reference can be obtained (type *)p is only the value without the object behind it and consequently it does not have the address.

Comment: `ptr` is an `int *`, not a `void *`, therefore `&ptr` has type `int **`. [You can't implicitly convert to `void **`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161649/explicit-cast-required-to-pointer-to-void-pointer) as it puts the conversion outside the scope of the representation.

Comment: @Leushenko it does matter in this question as only one has the valid systax.

Comment: DV? Any reason ?

Comment: `int *n; void *p = &n;` this is no-go. It will compile but will crash sooner-or-later when you reuse it back.

Comment: @tlrz of course but he asked another question which I have answered. What is the difference? The difference is: one will compile (abstracting from the sense of it), the second will not.

Answer (score -5):

It is the same behaviour while casting with int :

```
int a;
int *ptr = &(int)a;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? This does not explain the difference of the 2 statements.

Comment: @Gerhard it will not compile at all

Comment: I am not all-knowing but `int *ptr = &(int){a};`works fine.

Comment: @P__J__ correct, and the OP already noticed that. That is the reason why the OP asked in the first place.

Comment: `&(int){a}` is a completely different case. It is taking the address of an anonymous object of type `int` that was initialized to `a`.